# Kendo UI Grid - Checkbox filter issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are facing one issue with Kendo UI grid. (We are evaluating it, so no license copy as of now)

Scenario is:

1. We need to show data in Grid component.
2. For each column, we will have filter in form of multi select list box (see image attached).
3. We tried Kendo UI trial copy, and were successful to set data in it.
4. When we tried setting items in filter box, they appear to be blank.

Following is JSON which provides list of items in filter:

data which should be displayed in that  dropdown list

```
[
  {
    "id": 67,
    "name": "Investigation ESP"
  },
  {
    "id": 88,
    "name": "Refuse & Pickups"
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "name": "Dead Bug Removal"
  }
]
```

5. Can you share proper example or point our mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please try to combine the following two things...

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

http://www.telerik.com/forums/multi-select-with-checkboxes-plugin

Comment: Got this:vendor.js:32 TypeError: e.slice is not a function
    at me.extend.success (kendo.all.js:6621)
    at Object.me.extend.read.n._queueRequest.n.online.n.transport.read.success (kendo.all.js:6555)
    at success (srView.multiple.controller.js:128)
    at l (vendor.js:32)
    at vendor.js:32
    at f.$eval (vendor.js:33)
    at f.$digest (vendor.js:33)
    at f.$apply (vendor.js:33)
    at a (vendor.js:32)
    at g (vendor.js:32)